# How to understand this torque equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, free-body-diagram, buoyancy, fluid-statics

Here is a task where I need to write the torque equation (or moment equation) around A

[image]

Where forces G1 and G1 exist because of gravity, and force Fb because of buoyancy. In my mind, only forces G1 and Fb act on the stick, so the equation should  be

Fb*L - G1*L1=0

But the correct solution states:

Fb*L-G2*L-G1*L1=0

Can someone explain why does the mass of the triangle object matter, and why is it included in the equation.

Isn't that like putting a book on a table and saying that if the table was heavier it would exert larger force on the book?

Answer (score 1):

Hear Fb is the force acting on the triangle an not on the stick. The thing which is keeping the stick in equilibrium is the normal contact force between triangle and stick which is: 
                                Normal force=(Fb-G2)

so the final equation is :      (N*L)-(G1*L1)=0

```
                       i.e. (Fb-G2)*L-(G1*L1)=0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The buoyancy force $F_b$ does not act on the stick, it acts on the red triangle.

The red triangle is floating so the forces on it are balanced. These forces are : buoyancy force $F_b$, the weight of the triangle $G_2$, and the downward force $N$ from the stick : $$G_2+N=F_b$$
The force which the triangle exerts on the stick is equal and opposite to $N$ (Newton's 3rd Law).